# Solving large-scale binary integer program

Tags: computational-mathematics, integer-programming, discrete-optimization, binary-programming

I am working on the following hitting set problem: given a set $X$ and a collection $S$ of subsets of $X$ (which cover $X$), find the largest subset $X^*$ of $X$, such that each subset of the cover $S$ is hitted by at most one element of $X^*$.

I formulated this problem as a binary integer program (BILP), where the binary variables represent the elements of $X$, the constraints ensure that each subset of the cover contains at most one element of the solution $X^*$ and the objective is the maximization of the sum over the variables.

I'm using GUROBI (via MATLAB) to solve the BILP. GUROBI succeeds in solving an instance with 6!=720 variables and 450 constraints in less than 4 minutes. But it is not able to solve the next instance with 7!=5040 variables and 7350 constraints.

Does anybody know a more indicated software for this task or a platform where large LPs can be submitted in order to be solved by experts? Thanks a lot.

Comment: This may be more of a limited RAM issue than a fast software issue.

Comment: Showing the Gurobi log can help in getting a better answer.

Comment: I'll try to get more information from the Gurobi log. I also think that on a more powerful machine it might work. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that, by tweaking some parameter settings, you can get Gurobi (or some other ILP solver) to solver your larger instances. (I agree with Erwin about showing the log.) You could also formulate the problem as a constraint satisfaction problem and try a constraint solver. I can't predict whether that would be faster than or slower than using an ILP solver.

Comment: The reformulation as a constraint satisfaction problem looks interesting. I'll try.  Do you know dedicated solvers for such problems? Or maybe Gurobi itself? Thank you Prubin for your help!

Comment: IBM's CPLEX Studio suite includes CP Optimizer, a constraint solver. There are also a variety of open-source solvers (just search for "constraint solver" plus your favorite programming language). Google's OR-Tools apparently contains one. (https://developers.google.com/optimization/cp/cp_solver)

Comment: Thanks for the useful hint. I will look for constraint solvers, as a MILP solver is a very general tool and maybe not ideal for the particular binary structure of my problem.

Comment: Is it correct that a constraint satisfaction problem can be formulated as a system of (linear) equations/inequalities of a set of variables (binary variables in my case)? Thank you again!

Comment: Constraint solvers can deal with continuous variables and linear constraints (including inequalities) to some degree, but that's not their strong suit. They're best with integer or binary variables, and they are designed with logical constraints in mind. So a typical cover constraint, which you would write as a sum of binary variables being at least 1, might be better expressed as a disjunction ("or") of those variables.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Now I'm trying to translate my hitting set problem from the BILP formulation to a constraint satisfaction problem. But I'm not sure how to formulate a constraint of the type $x_1+x_2+...+x_n \leq 1$  as a logical constraint suitable for a constraint solver.

Comment: If the variables are all binary, you could turn the constraint into a gaggle of implications of the form $x_i \implies \neg x_j$. That said, constraint solvers garner much of their potency from "global constraints". Unlike in the MIP world, global constraints can be unique to specific solvers (although I'd bet they all have the "all different" constraint in some form). So you might look for a constraint named something like "at most one of" in your solver of choice.